# Why my idToken expires in 1 day if in AWS Cognito I configured for 5 minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an React App associated with my AWS Cognito identity pool and in the Client Applications I setud as follows:

[image]

However Verifing the Cookie generated will Expire in 1 day:

[image]

Any idea How to fix this missmatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related with aws_user_pools_web_client_id. Please be sure you use the right user pool.